# How to sort custom objects according to a specific sort order using swift codable

Tags: swift, sorting, codable

How to sort custom objects swift codable according to a specific sort order.
I am using swift codable protocol.

```
{
    "data": {
        "team": [
              {
                "name": "XYZ",
                "designation": "Managing director - South Asia"
              },
              {
                "name": "XYZ",
                "designation": "Managing director - South Asia"
              }
            ],
        "recruiterName": "Lorium Ipsem text",
        "respondsQuickly": "1"
    },
    "metaData": {
                "sortOrder": [
                  "respondsQuickly",
                  "recruiterName",
                  "team"
                ]
              }
}
```

Here I need to sort data objects according to sortOrder object.
This is a Model object now

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
let data: DataClass?
let metaData: MetaData?
}
struct JDDataClass: Codable {
   let team: [Team]?
   let recruiterName, respondsQuickly: String?
}

struct Team: Codable {
   let name, designation: String?
}
struct JDMetaData: Codable {
let sortOrder: [String]?
}
```

I can not look for All Keys also as its a model.
It's not a JSON or Dictionary now as its a custom object of Codabale protocol swift.

Desired Output:

```
let myArray = [
        {"respondsQuickly": "1"},
        {"recruiterName": "Lorium Ipsem text"},
        {"team": [
              {
                "name": "XYZ",
                "designation": "Managing director - South Asia"
              },
              {
                "name": "XYZ",
                "designation": "Managing director - South Asia"
              }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Your json is not valid, please post a proper json message. I assume the `JDDataClass` is also part of an array otherwise there would be no point in sorting on `recruiterName`for instance

Comment: Please clarify what your question is as well. Your last code example can't be understood, what is `responseDTO`and what is `data`and why are you assigning an int to a string?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson done changes

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. The value in your `"data"` key is a `Dictionary`, but you want to convert it to an `Array` which isn't anything useful to my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working playground code. You can check it. I hope this will help. arrResult is holding your answer.

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
let data: JDDataClass?
let metaData: JDMetaData?
}
struct JDDataClass: Codable {
let team: [Team]?
let recruiterName, respondsQuickly: String?
}

struct Team: Codable {
let name, designation: String?
}
struct JDMetaData: Codable {
let sortOrder: [String]?
}

let multiLineString = """
{
"data": {
"team": [
{
"name": "XYZ",
"designation": "Managing director - South Asia"
},
{
"name": "XYZ",
"designation": "Managing director - South Asia"
}
],
"recruiterName": "Lorium Ipsem text",
"respondsQuickly": "1"
},
"metaData": {
"sortOrder": [
"respondsQuickly",
"recruiterName",
"team"
]
}
}
"""
extension Encodable {
subscript(key: String) -> Any? {
    return dictionary[key]
}
var dictionary: [String: Any] {
    return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONEncoder().encode(self))) as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
 }
 }
 let decoder = JSONDecoder()

 do {
if let data = multiLineString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false){
  let json = try decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: data)
    var arrResult = [[String : Any]]()
    if let sortOrder = json.metaData?.sortOrder {
       for item in sortOrder {
        if let data = json.data {
            if let obj = data[item] {
                arrResult.append([item: obj])
            }
        }
    }
        print(arrResult)
 }
 }
 } catch {
print(error)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sorting on a struct keys doesn't make any sense. when the cost of accessing each element is same why do you want to sort the variables of an object.**

Perhaps your current structure is wrong.

```
{
  "data": {
    "team": [
      {
        "name": "XYZ",
        "designation": "Managing director - South Asia"
      },
      {
        "name": "XYZ",
        "designation": "Managing director - South Asia"
      }
    ],
    "recruiterName": "Lorium Ipsem text",
    "respondsQuickly": "1"
  },
  "metaData": {
    "sortOrder": [
      "respondsQuickly",
      "recruiterName",
      "team"
    ]
  }
}
```

This would have made more sense, if you wanted the above mentioned output with a structure like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "keys": [
      "team",
      "recruiterName",
      "respondsQuickly"
    ],
    "values": [
      [
        {
          "name": "XYZ",
          "designation": "Managing director - South Asia"
        },
        {
          "name": "XYZ",
          "designation": "Managing director - South Asia"
        }
      ],
      "Lorium Ipsem text",
      "1"
    ]
  },
  "metaData": {
    "sortOrder": [
      "respondsQuickly",
      "recruiterName",
      "team"
    ]
  }
}
```

Still, if you want to achieve this output with your current structure you can use something like : [Reflection](https://github.com/bradhilton/SwiftKVC/tree/master/Pods/Reflection) to read the struct's properties at runtime and sort it accordingly. Needless to say, this solution is ugly and should be avoided.